# Problem colorizing with GIMP

Tags: gimp, layers

Just started experimenting colorizing with GIMP. When I add a layer on the pop up window I choose foreground color (which has been set previously) however I keep getting a grey shade no matter what color has been chosen before. Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Hi nadineDinDin, welcome to GDSE. Can you please include a screenshot and elaborate more on the issue you're having.

Comment: will definitely do next time , issue solved :D

Comment: Your image is in Greyscale mode. Click Image > Mode > RGB. That'll fix it. No need to create a new document!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the problem was the image used the greyscale mode.
Simply changing the color mode to RGB fixed the issue.
-> Image -> Mode -> RGB

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same when I had chosen my new image to have greyscale colors, not RGB. That must be selected in the advanced options in File > New.

The user interface happily allowed me to choose any FG color, but new layer was greyscale, if it were not selected to be transparent.

So, open a new image and select the Colour space = RGB.

Comment: That worked perfectly :D thanks for your help

Comment: You can change that later in the Image -> Mode dialog, too.